# Making every module in a package accessible from within?

Tags: python, package, directory-structure, relative-import

How is a Python package supposed to be structured to make everything possible for any module inside of it?

My file structure is as follows:

```
Project/
    |---log/
    |   |---some logs
    |
    |---src/
        |---foo/
        |   |---__init__.py
        |   |---analyse.py
        |   |---export.py
        |    
        |---bar/
        |   |---__init__.py
        |   |---log.py
        |   |---dbhandler.py
        |   
        |---__init__.py
        |---main.py
```

`main.py` initialises everything. I want to import `foo/analyse.py` to `bar/dbhandler.py`, but I only receive an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'analyse'
```

I've tried several statements:

```
import Project.src.foo.analyse
import src.foo.analyse
import foo.analyse
import analyse
```

All of them give the same error. I've also tried:

```
from .. import foo.analyse
from .. import analyse
```

But I received:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

I've gone through about fifty threads on StackOverflow and countless articles on the internet. From everything I've found the `import src.foo.*` statement should work from anywhere inside the package, if only the `__init__.py` file is located in each folder.

Did anyone have the same problem?

Comment: What does "I want to import foo/analyse.py to bar/dbhandler.py" mean?  Are you trying to `import foo.analyse` in `bar/dbhandler.py`?  Or are you trying to import them both into `main.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your PYTHONPATH contains `Project/src` and then use

```
import foo.analyse
```

Comment: The problem was in appending it too late. Now it's working fine. I'm appending it in the beginning of the src.__init__.py file

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
from ..foo import analyse
```

Since it's undetermined what `..` by itself means: that probably just refers to the top level package, so you have to state which other branch of your package tree you want to go down: `foo` in this case.

With that, I can do (provided `src` is on your `PYTHONPATH`. In this case, I just started on the `Project` directory level):

```
>>> import src
>>> import src.bar
>>> import src.bar.dbhandler
>>> src.bar.dbhandler.analyse
<module 'src.foo.analyse' from 'src/foo/analyse.py'>
>>> src.bar.dbhandler.analyse.__file__
'src/foo/analyse.py'
```

Also, as you may notice, with your current structure, the "main" package is called `src`, since that's where your top-level `__init__.py` lives. Possibly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Given your directory structure, on main.py  you should have:

```
import foo.analyse
import bar.dbhandler
```

And then call like this (e.g.):

```
foo.analyse.number_cruncher()
bar.dbhandler.db_store()
```

if you start the program from the directory `main.py` is in, it should work as it is. Otherwise you should check your `PYTHONPATH` as Nicola Musatti suggests, or use a .pth file or any of the many options you have.